A conjecture on diagonal Ramsey numbers
Let $R(n,n)$ denote the $n$-th diagonal Ramsey number, i. e. the smallest integer $m$ such that any $m$-vertex graph contains either an $n$-clique or an $n$-independent set. Let us define a maximal $n$-Ramsey graph as a graph with $R(n, n)-1$ vertices that contains neither an $n$-clique nor an $n$-independent set. It is natural to conjecture that among maximal $n$-Ramsey graphs there exist self-complementary vertex-transitive graphs, i. e. graphs that are isomorphic to their complement, such that for any pair of their vertices $u$ and $v$, there exists an automorphism $a$ such that $a(u)=v$. This hypothesis is supported by the Paley graphs $P(5)$ and $P(17)$, which are respectively maximal $3$-Ramsey and $4$-Ramsey graphs (and simultaneously self-complementary and vertex-transitive).
My question is likely quite complex, but nevertheless, what is your assessment of the proposed hypothesis? It is useful to note that the validity of the hypothesis implies the regularity and oddness of the number of vertices in maximal Ramsey graphs, hence all diagonal Ramsey numbers must be even.
Addition. It is noteworthy that $5$-Ramsey graphs are not Paley graphs. This follows from the known estimate $43\leq R(5,5)\leq 48$ and the fact that within the range from $42$ to $47$, there are no prime powers congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, indicating there are no Paley graphs with the specified number of vertices.

"The actual value of R(5,5) is widely believed to be 43..." from here
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08768
